# How to access iCloud email to unlock because of a lost passcode

Tags: icloud, password

My kid forgot her passcode. We realize that to get it she will lose all data I've followed direction on other site but it always tells me to it will send an email and to follow instructions. Duh I can't open the iPad to read the email. Have tried setting up a secondary iCloud account on my iPad after the fact but that won't work either it seems she didn't fill in personal info for that option. Help!

Answer (score 1):

The support team should be able to help you in this case:

https://getsupport.apple.com/